# Java when a new thread start?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I doing some multitasking logic.

i want to know that **when a new thread is create by java** ? I thinks its just by invoking **thread.start()** or something else ?

Actual place of generation new thread into memory by **JVM(Java)** or **DVM(Android)**

Java's creators have graciously designed two ways of creating threads: implementing an interface and extending a class. Extending a class is the way Java inherits methods and variables from a parent class. In this case, one can only extend or inherit from a single parent class. This limitation within Java can be overcome by implementing interfaces, which is the most common way to create threads. (Note that the act of inheriting merely allows the class to be run as a thread. It is up to the class to start() execution, etc.)

That's mean whenever `thread.start()` will invoke a new thread is generated in memory .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitely, yes, it's on the `Thread.start()` method. This is not the only one way, however, as there are other data structures that internally start a `Thread` without explicitely issuing a `.start()` on it. It's the case of `AsyncTask`, where a `Thread` is created upon the `.execute()` statement.

In the case of `ThreadPoolExecutor` there's no need of the `.start()` as it's handled by itself.

Answer (score 3):

It's created when you call thread start yes. However various libraries will call thread start themselves, for example if you create a ThreadPoolExecutor that will manage its own threads.

Really this question is too broad, you need to drill down and ask more specifically what you actually need to know.

Comment: Thanks Tim B i want to know that actual place of generation new thread in memory by JVM or DVM.

Answer (score 1):

Yes ,Thread.start() is to start a thread,  A thread pool manages the pool of worker threads, it contains a queue that keeps tasks waiting to get executed

Please visit

**http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html**

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

http://www.journaldev.com/1069/java-thread-pool-example-using-executors-and-threadpoolexecutor

http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/03/12/java-executor-framework-tutorial-and-best-practices/

However Creating a thread in Java is done like this:

```
  Thread thread = new Thread();
```

To start the thread you will call its start() method, like this:

```
thread.start();
```

create a subclass of Thread and override the run() method. The run() method is what is executed by the thread after you call start(). Here is an example:

```
  public class MyThread extends Thread {

    public void run(){
       System.out.println("MyThread running"); 
    }
  }
```

To create and start the above thread you can do like this:

```
MyThread myThread = new MyThread();
  myTread.start();
```

You can also create an anonymous subclass of Thread like this:

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
      System.out.println("Thread Running");  
    }
  }

  thread.start();
```

The another way to specify what code a thread should run is by creating a class that implements java.lang.Runnable. The Runnable object can be executed by a Thread.
Here is a Java Runnable example:

```
  public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    public void run(){
       System.out.println("MyRunnable running");
    }
  }
```

To have the run() method executed by a thread, pass an instance of MyRunnable to a Thread in its constructor. Here is how that is done:

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
   thread.start();
```

anonymous implementation of Runnable, like this:

```
   Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable(){

     public void run(){
        System.out.println("Runnable running");
     }
   }


   Thread thread = new Thread(myRunnable);
   thread.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create Threads by either implementing Runnable interface of by extending Thread Class.

The following code creates thread.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
@Override
public void run() {
}
```

});

for multi threading you can try this tutorial:
http://www.journaldev.com/1079/java-thread-tutorial